# Is there any way in foundry by which we can validate the attachment while uploading it to ontology object type using attachment property?

Tags: typescript, attachment, ontology, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

Is there any way in foundry by which we can validate the attachment while uploading it to ontology object type using attachment property?

I have one ontology object type which has attachment property. I would like to add upload file to this ontology object type using function backed actions. But, before adding file, I want to validate the file like whether file contains particular data or not.

How can we achieve it using typescript?

I have created normal action type which uploads the file but it doesn't have option to validate the attachment.